# ImportError (circular import) in Django

Tags: python, django, import, model

everyone!
I need to delete my django app. After I do this, in another app I get ImportError. Apps don't have any connections at all.
But if in the first app in models I restore one line with import, everything goes well.

My structure
app_one/models.py --- need to delete

app_two/models.py
app_two/service.py

app_three/tasks.py

When I try to delete everything from app_one/models.py -> ImportError occured. But when I restore one line

```
from app_three.tasks import some_task
```

everything is ok

I checked everything - there are no real circular imports in theese three apps

If someone faced issue like this, I will appreciate your help

I tried to move this import to app_two/apps.py AppsConfig.ready, also I tried to move this import higher to another app which initialized before app_two. Nothing helped

Code:
app_two - mapping_service ->

```py
from double_gis.models import DoubleGisCompanyState
```

app_two - double_gis.models ->

```py
from company.models import Brand, BrandFeature, Company, Owner, get_pydantic_for_features

class DoubleGisCompanyState(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       verbose_name = _('2GIS Company state')
       verbose_name_plural = _('2GIS Companies states')

    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, verbose_name=_('company'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('state'), max_length=32, choices=states, db_index=True)
    state_changed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False, verbose_name=_('State changed at'),)
    double_gis_id = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('2GIS ID'), max_length=128, default=None, null=True, blank=True, unique=True,
    )
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/double_gis/models.py", line 34, in <module>
    from double_gis.client import AddressDetails, BranchDetails, OrganizationCommonFields
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/double_gis/client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from company.modules.reviews.services.review_abuse_service.exceptions import ReviewDoesNotExists
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/company/modules/reviews/services/review_abuse_service/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .services import CatalogReviewAbuse, ReviewAbuseService
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/company/modules/reviews/services/review_abuse_service/services.py", line 17, in <module>
    from company.modules.reviews.tasks.reviews_microservice import send_abuse_to_reviews_microservice
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/company/modules/reviews/tasks/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from company.modules.reviews.tasks.notifications import (
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/company/modules/reviews/tasks/notifications.py", line 14, in <module>
    from company.modules.reviews.services import notifications
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/company/modules/reviews/services/notifications/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from company.modules.reviews.services.notifications.builder_service import BuilderService
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/company/modules/reviews/services/notifications/builder_service.py", line 18, in <module>
    from double_gis_partnership.services import DoubleGisCompanyBrandMappingService
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/double_gis_partnership/services.py", line 31, in <module>
    from double_gis.mapping_service import ACLDoubleGisMappingService
  File "/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/double_gis/mapping_service.py", line 9, in <module>
    from double_gis.models import DoubleGisCompanyState
ImportError: cannot import name 'DoubleGisCompanyState' from partially initialized module 'double_gis.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/vaceslavksendzov/Desktop/RD/rocketdata/backend/app/double_gis/models.py)
```

So, error happens when I remove this line from first app

```
from app_three.tasks import some_task
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code and also the import error?  Django does lots of importing outside of the normal "from * import *" step, so it could be something in your settings or a migration file.  But given the line you added to fix it, it's tough to know without some code context or the error.

Comment: Did you delete the entire app, or just `models.py` of that app? In case of deleting the entire app, make sure to adjust your `settings.py` --> `INSTALLED_APPS`. Also **if you are still in development and you don't need to care about the database**, just delete the database and all migrations and go for `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.